# Let $A$ be a convex and closed subset of $\mathbb R²$ which not contains $0$. Show that there is a vectorial line separated from A.

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces, convex-geometry

I have not studied Hahn-Banach theorem yet, so I have to do without.
I made a drawing, it's quite clear on it :)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What about separation of $A$ and the origin by a hyperplane (=line)? Then the parallel line through the origin is going to be separated too by the same hyperplane.

Comment: I think it's the same drawing i made : taking the "shortest" line from the origin to A ; I draw its perpendicular line passing through the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r = \inf \{d(0,a) \mid a \in A\}$. By assumption $r > 0$. By definition $A \subset B(0,r)^c$.

Moreover there is a unique point $p \in A \cap \partial B(0,r)$. For the unicity, if there is two points on the boundary, then by convexity the segment between them is inside the circle, contradicting definition of $r$. The existence is because $A$ is closed.

As you said, take $L$ perpendicular to the segment $\overline{ Op}$. Assume there is a point $q \in L \cap A$. Then, by convexity the segment $\overline{qp} \subset A$. Now the segment $\overline{qp}$ intersect $\partial B(0,r)$ in some point $p' \neq p$ which is a contradiction by unicity of the point of the boundary.

Remark : if you are not convinced that $\overline{qp}$ intersect $\partial B(0,r)$ in another point that $p$, here is an algebraic proof. By rotating we can assume $p = (1,0)$ and $q = (0,y)$. The line between $p$ and $q$ is parametrized by $(1+t, - yt)$ (for example). Now we want to solve the equation $f(t) = 0$ where $f(t) = (1+t)^2 + (yt)^2 - 1$. A little calculation gives $t = \frac{-2}{y^2 + 1}$ is the desired point.

Comment: Sure, have a nice day too :)

Comment: I'm going hiking now, but I can take a look after.

Comment: Ok, have a nice hiking :D